# Pausing javascript async function until user action

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I have async function and I want it to execute to certain point, pause execution, and resume execution rest of function when user makes certain action (clicks a button for example). I tried this:

```
let changed = false;

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    if(changed){

        resolve('success');
    }else{

        reject('failure');
    }
});

async function test(){

    console.log('function started');
    console.log('before await');

    try{

        const fulfilledValue = await promise;
        console.log(fulfilledValue);
    }catch(failure){

        console.log(failure);
    }

    console.log('after await');
};

document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', function(){

    if(!changed){

        console.log('changed = true');
        changed = true;
    }else{

        changed = false;
    }
});

test();
```

However it doesn't work as I would like to. Async function doesn't wait till user action. As I understand it happens because promise is instantly rejected, because "changed" flag is initialy set to false. How can I fix this code to work as expected? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Can't you just complete the async action, save the result somewhere and then show it only after a button has been clicked ? Would that achieve the intended result for you ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use that `changed` flag at all. You cannot watch a variable or wait until it has a certain value (except for polling, but you don't want that). Instead, you should simply call the `resolve` callback from the click handler:

```
var clickPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        resolve(e);
    }, {once: true});
});
```

Comment: Good  one on `once`, the recipe for promisification is just `.addEventListener('click', resolve, {once: true})` then. But since `once` isn't well-supported, it would be better to remove a listener instead.

Answer (score 4):

You just need a way to resolve your Promise from outside, what about:

```
let outsideResolve;
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    outsideResolve = resolve;

});
```

You can now call outsideResolve from your click handler.

Comment: No. There's no reason to do it from outside.

Comment: I think this is a useful answer. It gives another approach that can be useful or simplify certain situations.

Comment: Here is an extended version https://jsfiddle.net/nvz13gp2/1/ . Note that the idea here is that the dialogs should be made modal, by covering the rest of the page when they are shown. I did not botther adding that here.